# Hibernation Sliver and sacrifices

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Hibernation Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hibernation%20Sliver) states all slivers have "*Pay 2 life: Return this permanent to its owner's hand*". So what if you have a sliver like [Necrotic Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Necrotic%20Sliver) that gives all slivers "*3, Sacrifice this permanent: Destroy target permanent.*"? Can you sacrifice a sliver and then return it to your owners hand before it goes into the graveyard?

Comment: Related: [Can I use Hibernation Sliver to return slivers from my graveyard?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/13753/5573) (you can't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot sacrifice a sliver to Necrotic Sliver's ability and then return it to your hand with Hibernation Sliver's ability.

When you activate Necrotic Sliver's ability, you sacrifice the creature as part of the cost. By the time the ability is on the stack and you have a chance to do anything else, the creature is already off the battlefield, so it cannot activate the other ability.